# How can I grab the id of foreign key to use as a column for bulk file imports?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-import-export

I'm working with the [Django import / export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to bulk upload models using an XLSX/CSV file.

I have two models - Company and Competitor. Competitor has a many-to-many relationship with Company. I want admin users to be able to upload a bunch of competitor names and be able to select which Company they all correspond to. I want the ID of the Company it corresponds to, to be marked in another column. How can I do this?

I have followed the instructions on the library's [Getting Started](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#importing) page but I just can't get the company ID to persist.

These are my models:

```py
# app/models.py

from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Competitor(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='The related company'
    )

    competitor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    competitor_website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In `forms.py` I've defined the custom forms allowing users to select from a list of already defined Company records.

```py
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from import_export.admin import ImportForm, ConfirmImportForm

from .models import Company, Competitor


class CompetitorImportForm(ImportForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Company.objects.all(),
        required=True
    )


class CompetitorConfirmImportForm(ConfirmImportForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Company.objects.all(),
        required=True
    )
```

Set up my import-export resources in `resources.py`

```py
from import_export import resources

from .models import Company, Competitor


class CompanyResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Company


class CompetitorResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Competitor
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
```

In `admin.py` I've subclassed the `ImportExportMixIn` to customise the interface and allow company selection.

```py
# app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportExportMixin

from .models import Company, Competitor
from .forms import CompetitorImportForm, CompetitorConfirmImportForm
from .resources import CompanyResource, CompetitorResource


class CompanyAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'website', 'theme', 'active', 'frequency')
    resource_class = CompanyResource


class CustomCompetitorAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CompetitorResource

    def get_import_form(self):
        return CompetitorImportForm

    def get_confirm_import_form(self):
        return CompetitorConfirmImportForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        # pass on `author` to the kwargs for the custom confirm form
        if isinstance(form, CompetitorImportForm):
            if form.is_valid():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                kwargs.update({'company': company.id})
        return kwargs


admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
admin.site.register(Competitor, CustomCompetitorAdmin)
```

The error message I'm receiving currently is:

```sh
Line number: 1 - (1048, "Column 'company_id' cannot be null")
```

because I haven't allowed nulls in my Competitor model. But it wouldn't be null if it would pull the id from the selected Company.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found the solution by following [this guide](https://www.oipapio.com/question-4146327).

First by using the `before_import_row` hook in my resource class in `resources.py`.

```py
# app/resources.py

class CompetitorResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def __init__(self, request=None):
        """
        This class uses Django sessions to carry the 'company' value from the import form to the import confirmation
          screen. We're not using sessions, so this gives another way to get the extra request data in. It works for
          both the dry-run preview and the actual import.
        :param request: Since 'self.request' doesn't exist in the default ModelResource we have to install it by giving
          competitor resource a custom constructor.
        """
        super(CompetitorResource, self).__init__()
        self.request = request

    class Meta:
        model = Competitor
        export_order = ('company', 'competitor_name')
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        company = self.request.POST.get('company', None)
        if company:
            self.request.session['import_context_company'] = company
        else:
            # If this raises a KeyError we want to know about it. It means that we got to a point of importing data
            #   without company context, and we do not want to continue.
            try:
                company = self.request.session['import_context_company']
            except KeyError as e:
                raise Exception(f'Company context failure on row import, check resources.py for more info: {e}')
        row['company'] = company
```

Then pulling that through in `admin.py` using the `get_resource_kwargs` hook.

```py
# app/admin.py

class CustomCompetitorAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'competitor_name', 'competitor_website', 'company')
    resource_class = CompetitorResource

    def get_import_form(self):
        return CompetitorImportForm

    def get_confirm_import_form(self):
        return CompetitorConfirmImportForm

    def get_resource_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The request isn't usually passed to the ModelResource constructor, so we need to add it to the kwargs dict for
          that call. Fortunately, Django Import/Export has a dedicated hook for that.
        :param request:
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        rk = super().get_resource_kwargs(request, *args, **kwargs)
        rk['request'] = request
        return rk
```

I can now select a foreign key field from a dropdown in form, pulling that through as a table column.